# Finding SubString in a string which contains a comma in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have string like below:

```
string s; //reading from front end like s='color'  
string s1; //reading from front end like s1='prototype'

string str=s+","+s1;
```

So `str="color,prototype"`

And string `str` can contain many strings like `str="color,prototype,niranjan,cloud";`

I want to send it to the database and it insert it into a table according rows like:

```
  id         value  
   1         color  
   2         prototye    
   3         niranjan   
   4         cloud
```

So a stored procedure or query to find the above requirement.

Comment: Why are you concatenating them into a single string?  Why not create a proc that takes in multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this if your sql server > 2000

```
DECLARE @S varchar(max),
  @Split char(1),
  @X xml

SELECT @S = '1,2,3,4,5',
  @Split = ','

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
```

Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85

else go forr a simple split function created at  : http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

Comment: just for representation, you can use t.c by p.q and t(c) by p(q)

Comment: please select my answer if that helped you